# How to check if logs has 7 consecutive days?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

## Objective

Below is the example data format. I need to get the in day 1, 2, 3, and so on.. On each account.

```
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
| m_idPlayer |   Start_Time   |    End_Time    | TotalPlayTime |   account    | SEQ |
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
|    0000001 | 20170202131759 | 20170202132311 |           312 | developer    |   1 |
|    0000001 | 20170202132351 | 20170202132615 |           144 | developer    |   2 |
|    0000001 | 20170202135834 | 20170202141342 |           908 | developer    |   3 |
|    0000002 | 20170202141645 | 20170202141814 |            89 | runewars21   |   4 |
|    0000003 | 20170202142341 | 20170202142559 |           138 | speedyturtle |   5 |
|    0000004 | 20170202142700 | 20170202142756 |            56 | kevlaire05   |   6 |
|    0000005 | 20170202142915 | 20170202143225 |           190 | infinity13   |   8 |
|    0000003 | 20170202142609 | 20170202143225 |           376 | speedyturtle |   9 |
|    0000002 | 20170202141820 | 20170202143721 |          1141 | runewars21   |  10 |
|    0000001 | 20170202142821 | 20170202143742 |           561 | developer    |  11 |
+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
```

- I need to check on that record if the user has logged in and played with a specific total play time (example: Day 1 - required to play  for 2 hours)
- Also check if the user has logged in for the consecutive days.

## Example expected results where account is developer

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| account   | player  | Day 1     | Day 2      | And so on |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| developer | 0000001 | 1925 secs | null       |           |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you please tag this question with whichever platform you're using, and add any code you've tried so far?

Comment: hi @sp_BlitzErik I've added sql-server-2008 for now I'm still searching for the possible solution.

Comment: Can we assume that we'll only ever have 7 days worth of data? Or will 7 days be arbitrary? If day 1 they are required to play for 2 hours, what about day 3? Does the amount of hours played vary based on day (or player id or something else)? You have an fun problem so I'd like to hear more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO your question requires a PIVOT solution.

CTE statment get the sum of seconds grouped by developer and day.

> ```
> SELECT   account, 
>          m_idPlayer AS player, 
>          SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Start_Time, End_Time)) Sec, 
>          DATEPART(DAY, Start_Time) as Dy
> from     logs
> GROUP BY account, m_idPlayer, DATEPART(DAY, Start_Time)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account      | player  |  Sec | Dy
> :----------- | :------ | ---: | -:
> developer    | 0000001 | 1984 |  2
> infinity13   | 0000005 |  190 |  2
> kevlaire05   | 0000004 |   56 |  2
> runewars21   | 0000002 | 1230 |  2
> speedyturtle | 0000003 |  514 |  2
> ```

PIVOT part, simply shows this data in columns. Keep in mind you must add all days of one month or deal with a dynamic query.

> ```
> WITH grp AS
> (
> SELECT   account, 
>          m_idPlayer AS player, 
>          SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Start_Time, End_Time)) Sec, 
>          DATEPART(DAY, Start_Time) as Dy
> FROM     logs
> GROUP BY account, m_idPlayer, DATEPART(DAY, Start_Time)
> )
>     SELECT account, player, [1], [2], [3], [4]
>     FROM
>     (SELECT account, player, Sec, Dy
>      FROM   grp
>     ) src
>     PIVOT
>     (SUM(Sec) FOR Dy IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) as Pvt
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> account      | player  |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4
> :----------- | :------ | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> developer    | 0000001 | null | 1984 | null | null
> runewars21   | 0000002 | null | 1230 | null | null
> speedyturtle | 0000003 | null |  514 | null | null
> kevlaire05   | 0000004 | null |   56 | null | null
> infinity13   | 0000005 | null |  190 | null | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=359a802b120a092838ef3bb09fea882c)*

In reference to the second (or main) question:

**How to check if logs has 7 consecutive days?**

I've used a STD solution, you can find it more by googling a bit.

**[SQL and contiguous data ranges.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2009/08/27/sql-and-contiguous-data-ranges.aspx)**

> ```
> create table logs
> (
> m_idPlayer varchar(20), 
> Start_Time datetime, 
> End_Time datetime, 
> TotalPlayTime int, 
> account varchar(20), 
> SEQ int);
> insert into logs values
> ('0000001','2017/02/02 13:17.59','2017/02/02 13:23:11',  312,'developer',1),
> ('0000001','2017/02/03 13:23:51','2017/02/03 13:26:15',  144,'developer',2),
> ('0000001','2017/02/04 13:58:34','2017/02/04 14:13:42',  908,'developer',3),
> ('0000001','2017/02/05 14:16:45','2017/02/05 14:18:14',   89,'developer',4),
> ('0000001','2017/02/06 14:23:41','2017/02/06 14:25:59',  138,'developer',5),
> ('0000001','2017/02/07 14:27:00','2017/02/07 14:27:56',   56,'developer',6),
> ('0000001','2017/02/08 14:29:15','2017/02/08 14:32:25',  190,'developer',8),
> ('0000001','2017/02/10 14:26:09','2017/02/10 14:32:25',  376,'developer',9),
> ('0000001','2017/02/11 14:18:20','2017/02/11 14:37:21', 1141,'developer',10),
> ('0000001','2017/02/12 14:28:21','2017/02/12 14:37:42',  561,'developer',11);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017/02/02';
> DECLARE @EndDate   datetime = '2017/02/12';
>
> WITH gpr AS
> (
> SELECT   account, 
>          m_idPlayer AS player, 
>          SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Start_Time, End_Time)) Sec, 
>          DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Start_Time])) as Dt
> from     logs
> GROUP BY account, m_idPlayer, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Start_Time]))
> ), grp2 AS
> (
>     SELECT account,
>            player,
>            Dt,
>            DATEDIFF(DAY, '17530101', Dt) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY Dt) AS GroupID
>     FROM gpr
>     WHERE Dt BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
> )
> SELECT     grp2.account,
>          grp2.player,
>          MIN(grp2.Dt )AS StartDate,
>          MAX(grp2.Dt) AS Enddate
> FROM     grp2
> GROUP BY grp2.account,
>          grp2.player
> HAVING    COUNT(*) >= 7;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account   | player  | StartDate           | Enddate            
> :-------- | :------ | :------------------ | :------------------
> developer | 0000001 | 02/02/2017 00:00:00 | 12/02/2017 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=47e0da9ee175d680224f118e572cf686)*

Comment: this is the new question http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168606/120741 I will try to update/provide my own dynamic query